# Can you delete a C-array of 1 integer as you would a normal integer?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, heap-memory, undefined-behavior

If I have a C-array `T* name = new T[1];`, can I delete it like this: `delete name;` since it only has 1 element, or is it undefined behaviour?

Or, to generalize the question, when you have an array `T* arr = new T[x];`, if you `delete arr;`, does it only delete the first element of the array, or does it depend from compiler to compiler?

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour, so it can do anything.

Comment: But normally, you would let `std::vector` do all of that for you.

Comment: That's the problem with raw pointers. Either use vector or smart-pointers for avoiding UB

Comment: Imagine you order one burger and ask for it on a tray.  You promise to return the tray after you eat your burger.  Instead, after finishing your burger you just throw its wrapper on the ground, steal the tray and set the building on fire.  That's what happens when you use array-alloc without the corresponding array-delete.

Answer (score 2):

You *have* to delete it with `delete[] name`.

Answer (score 2):

You always must match `new` with `delete` and `new[]` with `delete[]`. Mixing them will result in undefined behaviour.

```
T arr[x];
```

is something else entirely, it's an array with automatic storage duration. The memory will be automatically released when it goes out of scope. Trying to delete it will result in undefined behaviour.

And lastly there is no such thing as "deleting only the first element", when you allocate a block of memory, no matter how large it is, you muss deallocate the whole block.

---

Anyway, that's were standard containers like `std::vector` come in to make your life easier and hide all the complexity of memory (de-)allocation.

Comment: Yeah, the `T arr[x];` was my mistake, meant to write `T* arr = new T[x];`

Answer (score 1):

In order for the compiler to be able to use `delete[]` on an array, it would need to invoke the destructor of every element.  This would require that it to know not only the address of the first element (which it would get from the pointer) and the stride (which can be inferred from the element type), but also the number of elements.  To accommodate this, it is necessary to allocate space not only for the elements, but also for some kind of integer value indicating how many there are.  Thus, `new[]` would typically allocate slightly more space than needed to hold all the array elements, stores the count at the start of that space, and returns a pointer the portion of the allocation after the count.  Calling `delete[]` would subtract the size of the header from the supplied pointer, use the resulting pointer to retrieve the count, call the destructor on the appropriate number of array elements, and then delete the allocation that contained all of them.

While the exact details of how the count is stored will vary among different implementations, an understanding of the general principle should make it clear why the Standard makes no attempt to specify the effects of combining array `new[]` and non-array `delete`, or combining non-array `new` and array `delete[]`.